# In Jquery do you put quotes around document or leave it like below?

Tags: jquery

In Jquery do you put quotes around document or leave it like below?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


});
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `<document>` tag in HTML document, and in CSS you don't write `document > div {}` selectors. This is because `document` is native browser object. So the answer to your question is: no, you don't need quotes around `document`.

Answer (score 1):

`document` is an object and hence, it should not be in quotes.

For reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document

Answer (score 1):

Actually `ready`method doesn't care about the collection. `$().ready()`, `$('document').ready()` or `$(document).ready()` work the same. This means you just need to create a jQuery object (by calling the jQuery constructor) for using the `ready` method.

But if you want to refer to the `document` object that serves as an entry point into the web page's content you should use `document` not `"document".`

Answer (score 0):

`document` at  `$(document).ready()` does not require quotes , as `document` is an object property of `window` , not a jQuery selector. `document` at `$(document).ready()` sets `this` within [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) . Include quotes for selector , e.g., `$("body").ready(handler)` , where `this` within handler at `.ready(handler)` would be `body` element .